# support in Developing Code For TMG4903 sensor from AMS with Nordic 52 series

Tags: embedded, sensors, device-driver, nrf52

I am Working on AMS sensor TMG4903 with Nordic 52 series MCU.

these sensors are provided without Drivers and said that the firmware is directly in the sensor.
there are no code examples and any kind of support for this sensor.

If anyone has an Idea / worked on AMS TMG4903 sensor: https://ams.com/tmg4903#tab/documents

Kindly reply to me, to seek your help in understanding how to write the program for reading outputs.

Thanks in advance friends.

Comment: Starting on page 17 the Datasheet (found through your link) provides a description of the I²C protocol you have to use to communicate with the board. The nordic sdk contains examples for I²C

Comment: @M.Kotzjan do you have any example code on this sensor ??. and I am following the same thing, Let me try more.

Comment: I do not have a example for this specific sensor

Comment: let me know what you can help sir.

Comment: @M.Kotzjan do you have any code related to the AMS light sensor series? it might help to relate atleast.

Comment: I do not have any code examples other than the ones provided by nordic. I just thought you might be able to get something working using the register description from the datasheet and the examples. Have a look at the tw_sensor_example example in your sdk https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/topic/sdk_nrf5_v17.0.2/twi_sensor_example.html They are writing and reading data from a temperature sensor using the register addresses.